# WCF-Problema a la hora de implementar metodo con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, wcf

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en WCF. He creado un servicio y necesito implementar un metodo que devuelva una lista a partir de una consulta a Entity Framework uniendo varias tablas con joins. No sé si estoy haciendo bien

Este es el codigo:

```html
 public List<Object> GetPhones()
 {
            var ge = new gesphoneEntities();
            var phones = from ph in ge.tbl_phones
                         join phm in ge.tbl_phone_models on    ph.tbl_phone_model_id equals phm.ID
                         join phf in ge.tbl_phone_fabricants on phm.tbl_phone_model_fabricant_id equals phf.ID
                         select new object() { id = ph.ID, model = phm.Name };

            return (List<Object>)phones;
 }
```

Y el error que me da es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu problema es en el tipo de retorno. Tu variable `phones` es de de un tipo diferente a una lista. Ejecuta el método `ToList()` para crear una lista de la consulta ejecutandola. 
Prueba

```
return phones.ToList();
```

Comment: Eso tambien lo he probado y nada.

Answer (score 0):

la verdad es que me extraña mucho que se devuelva una `List<Object>` , a mi modo de ver deberías devolver una lista tipada.

```
  public List<Phone> GetPhones()
  {
       var ge = new gesphoneEntities();
       var phones = from ph in ge.tbl_phones
             join phm in ge.tbl_phone_models on    ph.tbl_phone_model_id equals phm.ID
             join phf in ge.tbl_phone_fabricants on phm.tbl_phone_model_fabricant_id equals phf.ID
             select new Phone() { id = ph.ID, model = phm.Name };

       return phones.ToList();
  }
```

Comment: No puede ser tipada con List<Phone> ya que es una Join con multiples tablas... y hay campos de la select que no son de la clase Phone.

Comment: Pero el que consume esa operación del servicio qué valor espera? Puedes editar tu pregunta mostrando el código del interfaz de tu servicio? Gracias

Comment: Espera un JSON. Y en la interfaz ya he definido que el meotodo devuelva un JSON.  [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: Hola, qué problema tienes con crearte una clase nueva `Phones` o `PhonesModel`(o como quieras llamarla) y aplicar la solución que te he dado en esta respuesta? Al final se devuelve un JSON al cliente que consume esa operación. Además, un `Object`cero que no es un tipo válido para WCF como valor de retorno

Comment: Pues porque está realizado con Entity Framework, y la propiedad Model 
en la clase Phone no existe. Mi pregunta es, que tipo de List debo devolver cuando se hace una query en LINQ con multiples joins.

Comment: Hola, entiendo que está realizado con EF pero lo que tu devuelves al cliente puedes "construirlo" como quieras, no hace falta que te ates a EF. En fin, te recomiendo lo dicho en esta respuesta (crear una clase y tipar  la salida de la operación). A ver si a algún compañero se le ocurre otra cosa.

Comment: Una solucion se me ha ocurrido crear una vista en la BD, y generar la clase a partir de esa vista. Y devolver una lista del tipo de esa clase.

Comment: También es buena esa opción... Pero al final devuelves la lista tipada :)

Comment: Es que una lista debe ir tipada.

Answer (score 0):

por qué mejor no usas una consulta LINQ que resulta más limpia y menos engorrosa. Otra cosa estas preguntando por Ids como phm.Id, phf.Id que al parecerme deberías haber pasado como parámetros. Espero te sirva de algo

Comment: Si lees el codigo, utilizo una consulta LINQ.

Comment: Disculpa amigo tienes toda la razón, me refería a utilizar expresiones landa.